# How do I change the size of a br tag to get more spacing between elements?

Tags: html

I've been developing a calculator in most of my free time. I increased the font size of the buttons using CSS and the br elements separating the clear and equate buttons don't provide enough spacing and therefore the buttons touch each other. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Change line-height of br tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you keep the `<br>` tag as is and use margins instead, as the `<br>` tag is intended to create a single line break between elements. Check [this page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br).

As a quick fix for an unimportant project, consider adding more `<br>` tags.

A better option would be to make use of margins in CSS. For example, you could add `margin-bottom` to the top button:

HTML

```
<!-- Clear button -->
<button class="mb">Clear</button>
<!-- Equate button -->
<button>=</button>
```

CSS

```
/* Add margin to button with the mb class*/
.mb {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

This would add a bottom margin of 20px to the top button. You could also add the margin as an inline style if necessary:
`<button style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Clear</button>`